# Two meshes stitched together

Tags: cloth-simulation

I want to simulate two pieces of fabric to act like they are stitched together so when I move a cloth, the outher cloth come with the first in a specific point of the mesh

Something like that (the last example with two meshes).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMVz2iafWt8

Comment: [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post an image](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: Probably apply a physics sim to the emptys that are hooked to the cloth mesh.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I want to simulate two pieces of fabric to act like they are stitched together